# Magento 1 - How to show bundle products original price and discount price in product listing page

Tags: magento-1, price, bundle

Am creating a **Combo Offer** using **Bundle** option in my store. I did everything, but need to show `Original Price` and `Special price` in product list page. Eg:

[image]

Comment: where can I find this? Go to price tag in price view change as As low as and click save Thank you!
Patrizia

Comment: @PatriziaVergassola i have alredy done this. Thanks for your commend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution, do some following steps

1. catalog->manage products->bundle product-1->edit
2. Go to price tag in `price view` change as `As low as` and click save
3. Go to cpanel app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml

`<?php echo $this->__('As low as') ?>` change to following code

```
<?php  
    $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
    $OrgPrice = $pro->getPrice();
    $OrgPrice1 = round($OrgPrice); 
?>
<span class="price" style="color: #FF2DFF;font-size: 20px;"><strike>
    <?php if (!$canApplyMAP): ?>
    <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($OrgPrice1,true,false) ?>
    <?php endif ?></strike>
&nbsp; </span>:
```

[image]